# Formatting RAISERROR messages in SYBASE ASE 12.5

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sap-ase, raiserror

In a stored procedure, I am trying to test if a parameter is null or less then 1, and if so, raise an error with a friendly message, and the value of the parameter.

Here is my code:

```
IF @ID IS NULL OR @ID <= 0
BEGIN
    RAISERROR 27001 'ID is ?????. ID cannot be null or less then zero.'
    RETURN 27001
END
```

What I would like back is either:

*"ID is 0. ID cannot be null or less then zero."*
or
*"ID is null. ID cannot be null or less then zero."*

I've tried building a varchar and raising the error like this:

```
RAISERROR 27001 @message
```

but that produces the error *"Message Number 27001, passed to RAISERROR, does not exist in the sysmessages catalog."*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, although an @ID value of NULL writes out as empty string.

```
IF @ID IS NULL OR @ID <= 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE @msg varchar(250)
    SELECT @msg = 'ID is ' +  Convert(varchar(15), @ID) + '. Value cannot be null or less then zero'

    RAISERROR 27001 @msg
    RETURN 27001
END
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is this:  You need to add your custom error # into the database by calling sp_addmessage:

```
sp_addmessage 27001, "ID is %1. ID cannot be null or less than zero."
```

You can then call RAISERROR like you have above, or like this (if you want to use the message string you defined in sp_addmessage):

```
RAISERROR 27001, @ID
```

EDIT:  (Addressing comment)

First, if you're so inclined just register 27001 with a positional argument as the message:

```
sp_addmessage 27001, "%1"
```

Second, you're not FORCED to display the default message that you've registered using sp_addmessage;  e.g., this ought to display a separate message regardless of what the default message is:

```
RAISERROR 27001 @message
```

Comment: This does work, but we reuse the range of 27000 - 27050 in all our procs.  In other words, 27001 in proc a is not necessarily 27001 in prob b.  So sp_addmessage is not an option for us.

Comment: Actually, sp_addmessage is an option (see edited section to see how) and as far as I know, it's must if you want to raise any custom error numbers.